# Python Homework prime numbers print

Tags: numbers

For HW I have to print all primes from a list:
Ex.

```
Numbers=[1,3,4,5,15,48,73]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: If you want someone help you with the homework you should show what have you done. So, please add code that you have done so far, and describe where you stuck.

Comment: Please refer to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and edit your question accordingly, this way you'll enhance the probability that someone will reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt

s = set(Numbers)
for i in s:
    if i%2==0:
        s.remove(i)
        continue
    for k in range(2, int(sqrt(i))+1, 2):
        if i%k==0:
        s.remove(i)
        continue
for i in s:
    print(i)
```

Try this.